# Using more than one past perfect tense with time clauses and "last time I..."

Tags: past-tense, time, past-perfect

I know I can express things in many different ways, and that maybe I could find alternative ways to form the sentences below, but I'm just trying to understand the use of the past perfect in certain situations so I'd like an answer to my questions.

1. Is using the past perfect more than once in the following way correct?:

> I remembered they **had said** that they **had hated** me (but didn't hate me
> at the time of saying)

2. Imagine asking person A a lot of questions after not seeing them in a year, and then your friend asks you: "Why did you ask them many questions?"

The reason is that person A had told you they weren't feeling well last time you'd talked, so which sentence would you use? :

> Because they **had told** me they (**hadn't been**/**weren't**) feeling well last time we (**had talked**/**talked**)

If I had to make a guess I would say the following:

> Because they **had told** me they **weren't** feeling well last time
> we **had talked**

and maybe this one also conveys the intended meaning:

> Because last time we **had talked** they **told** me they **weren't** feeling well

I've searched the web and asked this somewhere else already, I received a comment saying "it has to be "last time I saw", everything else is correct either way", which I doubt is true; the meaning in that case is not clear, I can't tell when the time of "saw" is relative to "told".

A [sentence](https://www.englishforums.com/English/LastTimeIWasHadBeen/ggbcw/post.htm) I found that might help:

> The last time I had been to the Newark airport had been September 10,
> when Todd and I had returned from Rome.

does it imply that the following sentence is correct?:

> We had been at the Newark airport when Todd and I had returned from
> Rome.

possible meanings I'd give it are "we were at the airport before the considered time, and that was when we returned from Rome", or "we returned from Rome before the considered time, and before our return we were at the airport"

I've seen a couple of answers saying that the past perfect can't ever be used more than once in a sentence, but I'm somewhat sure it's possible. These answers usually give examples along the lines of "I had been to the city when I visited them", even though the past perfect can be used in different structures/ways (an example of that which **might** be correct is "It had been six days since I had last seen them").

I'm aware I could have somehow expressed the sentences differently, but I want to understand the general rules and usage if possible.

Comment: You're way overthinking things. You should look for reasons to *avoid* using Perfect verb forms, rather trying to find places where you *can* use them. Lots of native speakers wouldn't use any Perfect verb forms at all in your *Because they had told me they hadn't been feeling well last time we had talked* context. Feasibly we might say ***hadn't been feeling well*** is "better" than ***weren't feeling well*** if it's important to emphasise the the person had been unwell ***before*** that last conversation (and was still unwell *during* the conversation?). But not the others.

Comment: In the phone call example I wouldn't use the perfect at all.  The timing of the events is clear from context.  Your Newark example looks like it might come from a story told in past tense, where the perfect is somewhat obligatory to establish the past of the past.